# Exception in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

I'm trying to implement the searchBar following steps in this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XuM3BCpESo)
But I got the following exception when I press the searchBar

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object <Authors: 0x10960c1e0>.'
```

AuthorsTableViewController.h

```
@interface AuthorsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> {
NSMutableArray *authorsArray;
NSMutableArray *resultArray;
QuotesNavController *quotes;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *SearchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *authorsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *resultArray;


-(sqlite3 *) openDataBase;
-(IBAction)backToQuotes:(id)sender;

@end
```

AuthorsTableViewController.m

```
#import "AuthorsTableViewController.h"

@interface AuthorsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AuthorsTableViewController

@synthesize authorsArray, resultArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self retrieveDataFromSqlite];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)backToQuotes:(id)sender{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToQuotes" sender:sender];
}


-(sqlite3 *) openDataBase{

sqlite3 *database;

NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SuccessQuotes" ofType:@"sqlite"];

if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");

}else{
    NSLog(@"database opened!");
}

return database;
}

-(void) retrieveDataFromSqlite{

 authorsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 sqlite3 *myDatabase = [self openDataBase];

 const char *sqlSelect = "SELECT *, COUNT(qu_author) AS count FROM authors JOIN quotes ON _auid = qu_author GROUP BY  au_name ORDER BY  au_name ASC";

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, sqlSelect, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        int author_id = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

        NSString *au_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

        NSString *au_picture = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

        int quotes_id = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 3);

        NSString *quotes_content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

        int quotes_author = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 5);

        NSString *quotes_favorite = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];

        int count = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 7);


        Authors *authors = [[Authors alloc] initWithUniqueId:author_id au_name:au_name au_picture:au_picture quotes_id:quotes_id quotes_content:quotes_content quotes_author:quotes_author quotes_author:quotes_author quotes_favorite:quotes_favorite count:count];

        [authorsArray addObject:authors];


    } // while end

 }// prepare end


sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

sqlite3_close(myDatabase);

}


- (void) searchThroughtData {
self.resultArray = nil; 

  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",self.SearchBar.text]];

 self.resultArray = [[self.authorsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    return [authorsArray count];
} else {
    [self searchThroughtData];
   return [resultArray count];
}

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
[self searchThroughtData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"authorCell";

AuthorsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (!cell) {
    cell = [[AuthorsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

Authors *temp_items;

if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    temp_items = [self.authorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    temp_items = [self.resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


[cell.authorName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp_items.au_name]];

[cell.count setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",temp_items.count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:temp_items.au_picture];

cell.authorPic.image = theImage;

UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:93/255.0
                                                  green:45/255.0
                                                   blue:22/255.0
                                                  alpha:0.5];
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;


return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Authors *temp_items = [self.authorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

quotes = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuotesNavController"];

quotes.quType = 3;
quotes.authorId = temp_items.author_id;
[self presentModalViewController:quotes animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: its crashing on sqlSelect statement. Enable All Exception breakpoints in Xcode and debug. This has nothing to do with UISearchBar.

Comment: I enabled it and the error is in this line ` self.resultArray = [[self.authorsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];`

Comment: what is the data structure of result object looks like. Also, what is the text returned by search bar ?that might be cause of problem.